# How to implement a Ctrl+C action in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I implement a combination(Ctrl+C) key pressed action in c# ?? I need the application to press the key (Ctrl+C) when the user click a button ??

I don't want it to detect the key press, because I did that already. I need the application to perform the Ctrl+C action when a button pressed, instead of pressing from the keyboard. Because I will use that for the Edit menu for my application ;)

Note: I just want it to do the Ctrl+C action, I don't want it to copy the text, because it's already done. Only I want is to press those key.

Thanks alot

Comment: Do you want to simply copy something to the clipboard?

Comment: Yep... But I want to do it by sending keyboard action only by pressing a button. Because, I have other methods that I have to send keyboard action rather than Ctrl+C. Ex: Ctrl+X,A,V... so on. So, for that reason, I want to do it by sending a keyboard action ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3w7761b.aspx) class methods [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) or [SendWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx)

Comment: thanks alot. it does works... I tried it before i post the question, but i was having problem with the Ctrl+C... the problem was because i use capital C for the send command instead of small C :) Thanks alot again

Comment: Then you want Ctrl + Shift + C, not?

Comment: I did it leppie, Thanks alot ;) I was Needing it only for Ctrl+C,A,V,X... 7 so on :) i didn't need the shift key with them ;)